# Chrome Extension - async JS

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, dom, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I have an extension that runs on a website that is loading many external scripts ,and the extension is running only a few seconds later.Is it possible to mark the content script as async so it won't wait for the page to load?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#run_time

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect in your background server worker script if the current tab is finished loading. And then execute your script:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId , info) {
  if (info.status === 'complete') {

     // Execute here your script
     const tabId = getTabId();
     chrome.scripting.executeScript(
         {
           target: {tabId: tabId, allFrames: true},
           files: ['script.js'],
         },
         () => { ... });
     //---

  }
});
```

Source: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/